# Uploading xls format file is giving error in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

I want to upload `.xls` and `.xlsx` format files. `.xlsx` format is working fine but while uploading `.xls` I am getting error as

> External table is not in the expected format

Here is my code which I tried

```
if (fluploadData.HasFile)
    {

        string filename = Path.GetFileName(fluploadData.FileName);
        // FileUpload.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/") + filename);
        string filenamewithoutrext = string.Empty;
        FileExt = Path.GetExtension(fluploadData.FileName).ToLower();
        if (Path.GetExtension(fluploadData.FileName).ToLower() != ".xls" &&
            Path.GetExtension(fluploadData.FileName).ToLower() != ".xlsx"
        )
        {

            Response.Write("Only .xls, .xlsx are allowed.!");
            return;
        }

        filenamewithoutrext = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fluploadData.FileName).ToLower();

        string path = Server.MapPath("UploadData\\");
        string filename_ = filenamewithoutrext;

        //   DeleteDirectory(path);
        if (!Directory.Exists(path))   // CHECK IF THE FOLDER EXISTS. IF NOT, CREATE A NEW FOLDER.
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                File.Delete(file);
            }
        }

        string fname;
        fname = path + filename_ + ".xls";

        fluploadData.SaveAs(fname);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["ExcelFilePath"] = fname;

        string conStr = "";
        System.Data.DataTable dtExcelRows = new System.Data.DataTable();

        switch (FileExt)
        {
            case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
                conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
            case ".xlsx": //Excel 07
                conStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07ConString"].ConnectionString;
                break;
        }

        conStr = String.Format(conStr, fname, "YES");

        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection connExcel = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(conStr);
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand cmdExcel = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand();
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter oda = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter();
        cmdExcel.Connection = connExcel;


        connExcel.Open(); // here is coming the error

        System.Data.DataTable dtExcelSchema = connExcel.GetOleDbSchemaTable(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
        System.Data.DataTable dtExcelColumnsTable = connExcel.GetSchema("Columns");
        //string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();
        string SheetName = dtExcelSchema.Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString().Replace('\'', ' ').Trim();  // nadeem
        cmdExcel.CommandText = "SELECT * From [" + SheetName + "]";
        oda.SelectCommand = cmdExcel;
        oda.Fill(dtExcelRows);
        connExcel.Close();
        bool Structure_FLG = false;
}
```

The connection string is also set up in web.config properly which is as below

```
<add name="Excel03ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR={1}'"/>
<add name="Excel07ConString" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR={1}'"/>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line will save all uploaded files into XLS format, regardless of uploaded file extension and may throwing exception when actual file format mismatch:

```
fname = path + filename_ + ".xls";
```

I suggest using file extension provided from `Path.GetExtension(fluploadData.FileName)` method:

```
string fname = path + filename_ + FileExt;
```

*External table is not in the expected format* error typically occurs when trying to read newer XLSX format with a connection string that uses Jet OLEDB 4.0 provider or vice versa, hence make sure that you're set [proper connection string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/) corresponding with uploaded file extension.

Comment: Is that error occurs only on certain file or all XLS files? What happened when you're trying to open created file manually in server? The connection string itself seems OK, the problem is that you're reading the file by wrong connection string/file format selection.

Comment: yes it occurs for only `xls` file ?? yes it opens  on server properly.

Comment: Possibly the Excel file contains mixed data columns, try adding `IMEX=1` for JET OLEDB connection string. Related issues [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6470f985-6aa6-4c10-97e6-88b2c8818c03/error-external-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format-when-read-file-excel-xls?forum=csharpgeneral) & [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/28788b08-d9d5-4b5b-9fff-31e250b0a358/xls-ampamp-xlscexternal-table-is-not-in-the-expected-format?forum=adodotnetdataproviders).